# Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

`Error: Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present at RequestManager.resolveRequest (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1190:15) at RequestManager.queueRequest (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1150:46) at REST.raw (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1396:32) at REST.request (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:33) at REST.put (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1370:17) at registerCommand (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\index.js:51:16) at start (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\index.js:458:11) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chris\Desktop\adbot\index.js:465:1) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)`

`const discordToken = process.env["MTEwMzcxNjY0NzMxNzAxMjQ4MA.GCviE2._V1WKQhWPjsCZJ3EWvy2rmKFKQnTmXnmjqOsw8"]; const channelId = process.env["1089592410360782908"]; const guildId = process.env["1089572362460078120"]; const clientId = process.env["1085245543208464455"];`

```
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(discordToken);
await rest.put(
    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
    { body: [activateCommand.toJSON(), statusCommand.toJSON(), deactivateCommand.toJSON()] },
);
```

}

Im getting some error i dont know about the token is 100% valid

Comment: What is `process.env["MTEwMzcxNjY0NzMxNzAxMjQ4MA.GCviE2._V1WKQhWPjsCZJ3EWvy2rmKFKQnTmXnmjqOsw8"]`, `process.env["1089592410360782908"]`, etc? That's not how you should use environment variables. Do you use the `dotenv` package?

Comment: Also, make sure to reset your discord token as it's exposed.